# Are all CMIS operations required to be synchronous?

Tags: specifications, synchronous, cmis

The [CMIS protocol specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/csprd01/CMIS-v1.1-csprd01.html) does not even contain the words "synchronous" or "asynchronous".

I guess that implicitely, every server-side operation is synchronous?
Are there counter-examples?

Scenario: I create a document, then immediately I list the directory, and the file does not appear yet.
Is this scenario illegal?
(not a client problem, the client waits for HTTP response before going to the next instruction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMIS is synchronous, and doesn't have any semantic for transactions spanning multiple requests. Thus, each successful mutation request (`POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` in the AtomPub binding) have immediate effect to subsequent requests.

The scenario you depicted is not illegal, it's simply impossible to achieve under CMIS. If you need asynchronous operations, you need to decouple the client from CMIS and introduce an intermediate layer that e.g.:

- caches the pre-execution state of a CMIS mutation
- returns the cached value until the mutation is successful.

Comment: Thanks! I don't **need** asynchronous operations, I was actually afraid that they might exist :-)

Comment: then consider yourself on the safe side :-)

Answer (score 1):

In general CMIS operations are supposed to be synchronous. I don't know of any counter examples. Asychronous operation on the server would make it almost impossible to create applications.

Assuming you are using AtomPub under the covers, you might want to check 
http://bitworking.org/projects/atom/rfc5023.html . Creating a resource returns its URI.

So I guess what you are seeing is either a bug in the implementation or the client is using implemention details not covered by the spec. The alfresco repository for example indexes asynchronously by default (solr). Hence, I think it should be possible to come with code which demos the behavior you observe backing the listing by a search.